# Using Formal Class RasterLayer as RSAGA input and otput

Tags: r, saga

Is there a way to use the data from the R global environment object as input for an rsaga.geoprocessor alghoritm? And if yes, can be the output also saved as a same object? 
I am writing chain processes and the constant importing/exporting of results makes the whole process far from elegant, as you can see on the code below:

```
rsaga.geoprocessor("grid_filter", 15, env = env,
                    list(INPUT="AKV_mode_5.tif",
                    OUTPUT="AKV_OUTPUT.sdat",
                    MODE="Moore",
                    THRESHOLD=4,
                    ALL="single class",
                    CLASS=2))

AKV_2_3 <- raster('AKV_OUTPUT.sdat')

AKV_2_3_recl <- reclassify(AKV_2_3, cbind(NA, 3))

writeRaster(AKV_2_3_recl, 'AKV_OUTPUT_2.tif', options="COMPRESS=LZW") 

rsaga.geoprocessor("grid_filter", 15, env = env,
               list(INPUT="AKV_OUTPUT_2.tif",
                    OUTPUT="AKV_OUTPUT_3.sdat",
                    MODE="Moore",
                    THRESHOLD=4,
                    ALL="single class",
                    CLASS=3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in the RSAGA package without a massive restructuring.

RSAGA works by running an external `saga_cmd` command, which starts a new process that does input and output via files.

To do otherwise could be done, but it would require dynamically linking to the SAGA C++ code, and writing R to C++ wrappers (which would probably be best done using Rcpp). This is not a trivial task.

I think the Python SAGA API does this, so if file I/O is a real bottleneck problem you might consider rewriting your critical analysis code to use that instead of R.

Comment: Ok, I will do it in Python then, thank you @Spacedman!